# Recursion sequences python

Tags: python, list, recursion, sequence, repeat

how can I print all sequences of length n containing letters from a list (that can repeat themselves)? **using recursion**.
for example:

```
seq = ['a', 'b']
n = 2
```

output:

```
aa,ab,ba,bb
```

I've been looking up and could only find recursive programs that give all sequences with **no** repetition. furthermore, I couldn't find any solution regarding a given list (most of them are given strings)

one of the problems is that I'm not sure how to address the function recursively while it contains the length n.

Comment: You are looking for PSL [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module

Comment: cannot use any module ;( @jlandercy

Comment: Is it an homework or an assignment? If so please add the `homework` tag and state it in your post.

Comment: itertools is part of Python Standard Library. It comes with Python

Answer (score 4):

You can recruse on `n`, the length of the subsequence. If `n == 0`, there is only one subsequence - the empty one. Otherwise, you take all pairs of elements of your list and subsequences of length n-1, and get all subsequences of length `n`.

```
def subseqs(lst, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return [[]]
    else:
        return [[x] + xs for x in lst for xs in subseqs(lst, n - 1)]
```

Comment: thanks. can you explain what xs means? also, would this work for longer sequences? (for example ['a','b','c'] ) @Yakym Pirozhenko

Comment: This would work for longer sequences; `xs` is a part of a _list comprehension_ - you could look at examples in the documentation. You can accomplish the same task with two for loops, but that may be less elegant from Python standpoint.

Comment: In this case, `xs` stands for a subsequence of length `n-1`.

Answer (score 1):

I will use itertools

```
import itertools

seq = ['a', 'b']
n = 2

print([i+j for i,j in itertools.product(seq,repeat=n)])
```

This is a task for product ;)

BTW: if you don’t want modules look at source code:

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100     101 110 111
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Source code at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Learn and Reverse engineering it to fit your need ;). Example if you don’t want it to return tuples.

Comment: I think that OP does not want to use `itertools`. Otherwise, you could also use `combinatons_with_replacement` of the shelf.

Comment: He can look at source code and rewrite itertools product function ;)

Comment: Probably will be educational, although I think that product is implemented in C for efficiency.

Comment: Pedantic, but here is the actual source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9718b59ee5f2416cdb8116ea5837b062faf0d9f8/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L2090 The snippet above is a Python analog.

Comment: Probably he wants it in Python layer ;)

Answer (score 1):

### One of the ways to solve this is to use `itertools.product`

```
import itertools

seq = ['a', 'b']
n = 2

for a, b in itertools.product(seq,repeat = n): print (f"{a}{b}") #loop through all the products and print them

#result --> 
# aa
# ab
# ba
# bb
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, using only recursion. The `findSeqRecPerChar` finds all possible combinations for a specific character in the list and the `findSeqRec` find all possible combinations for every character:

```
seq = ['a', 'b']
n = 2

def findSeqRecPerChar(seq,n,elem,index):
    if index == n:
        return []
    else:
        return [elem+seq[index]] + findSeqRecPerChar(seq,n,elem,index+1)

def findSeqRec(seq,n,index,l):
    if index == n-1:
        return l + []
    else:
        l.extend(findSeqRecPerChar(seq,n,seq[index-1],0))
        return findSeqRec(seq,n,index+1,l)

result = findSeqRec(seq,n,-1,[])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb']
```